# py.test "--collectonly doesn't respect -k" issue is not fixed?

Tags: python-2.7, pytest

I have encountered the problem described in this py.test problem report:
https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/pytest/issue/27/collectonly-doesnt-respect-k

These are the results from the Jenkins console:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + py.test -v -k test_example --junitxml=functionaltests/reports/res.xml
    ============================= test session starts ==============================
    platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.3 -- pytest-2.3.4 --         /var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/9df20569/virtualenvs/701cc1aa/bin/python2.7
    plugins: xdist
    collecting ... collected 3 items / 1 errors

```
functionaltests/test_example.py:40: test_data[apple] PASSED
functionaltests/test_example.py:40: test_data[pear] PASSED
functionaltests/test_example.py:40: test_data[berry] PASSED

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
___________ ERROR collecting functionaltests/test_smm_healthcheck.py ___________
functionaltests/test_smm_healthcheck.py:2: in <module>
>   import models.SMMMicrosites as site_data
E   ImportError: No module named models.SMMMicrosites
 generated xml file: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/WT/functionaltests/reports/res.xml 
====================== 3 passed, 1 error in 0.05 seconds =======================
Build step 'Virtualenv Builder' marked build as failure
Recording test results
Finished: FAILURE
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

The test module "test_smm_healthcheck.py" should not be collected or executed. Has the fix -- this is resolved -- not been released? I'm running py.test version 2.3.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "-k" flag does not influence what is collected - only what is reported with --collectonly.  So you can't use it to prevent collection.  You can use --ignore=path (once or multiple times) to prevent collection.